# symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7 (when running Archive in Xcode and Python3)

Tags: python, ios, python-3.x, xcode, kivy

When I try to create an archive failed build. The project run ok on IOS simulator and run over python3 + kivy-ios and there are all warnings and errors:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/XX/kivy-ios/glomarkhome-ios/../build/lib'
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-F/Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/frameworks'
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libsdl2_ttf.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libsdl2_ttf.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libpyobjus.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libpyobjus.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libffi.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libffi.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libfreetype.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libfreetype.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libsdl2_image.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libsdl2_image.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libsdl2_mixer.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libsdl2_mixer.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libcrypto.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libcrypto.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libssl.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libssl.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libsdl2.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libsdl2.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libios.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libios.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libkivy.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libkivy.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libpython3.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/XX/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libpython3.a (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_PyEval_InitThreads", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in main.o
  "_PyMem_RawMalloc", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in main.o
  "_PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in main.o
  "_PyRun_SimpleStringFlags", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in main.o
      _load_custom_builtin_importer in main.o
  "_PySys_SetArgv", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in main.o
  "_Py_DecodeLocale", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in main.o
  "_Py_Finalize", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in main.o
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in main.o
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
     (maybe you meant: _SDL_main)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

All librareis are include on Build Phases > Link Binary
Any idea?

Comment: Check your folder name it might be an issue, no space accepted

Comment: Confirmed. There are no spaces in the name of the folder.

Comment: Or any other folder or framework that you need to copy and paste in project dir please check also, Means that take refernace

Comment: Confirmed. There are no spaces in the names of any folder in the whole project. I don´t copy and paste nothing.

Comment: I delete all path from project on Build Settings > Search Paths and now I have only one Error and no Warnings

Comment: I have started everything from the beginning and I realized that maybe I do not have kivy-ios for armv7 and I have executed: `./toolchain.py build python3 kivy --arch=armv7 --arch=arm64` and tell me `[ERROR ] Architecture armv7 invalid`

Comment: I solved my problem and it was really simple. I put on Build Settings > Architectures >Architectures: `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved my problem and it was really simple. I put on Build Settings > Architectures >Architectures: `$(ARCHS_STANDARD_64_BIT)`

Comment: hello! but what if we need to support armv7 devices? is there any way to build the project, but make this particular feature disabled if device has armv7 architecture?