# ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7, previous answers not enough

Tags: python, xcode, kivy

When I'm building my Xcode 10.2 app I'm getting an error.

I've tried:

- delete the path under Framework Search Paths
- add MobileCoreServices.framework (any I've tried many others)
- answers from older questions like [‘ld: warning: directory not found for option’](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9458739/ld-warning-directory-not-found-for-option)

Sadly it doesn't help.

Warnings:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/davidarchibald/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libssl.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/davidarchibald/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libssl.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/davidarchibald/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libsdl2_ttf.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/davidarchibald/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libsdl2_ttf.a (2 slices)
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/davidarchibald/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libpyobjus.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /Users/davidarchibald/kivy-ios/dist/lib/libpyobjus.a (2 slices)
```

and errors:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_PyEval_InitThreads", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in main.o
  "_PyRun_SimpleFileExFlags", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in main.o
  "_PyRun_SimpleStringFlags", referenced from:
      _load_custom_builtin_importer in main.o
  "_PySys_SetArgv", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in main.o
  "_Py_Finalize", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in main.o
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in main.o
  "_Py_SetPythonHome", referenced from:
      _SDL_main in main.o
  "_main", referenced from:
     implicit entry/start for main executable
     (maybe you meant: _SDL_main)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

On the simulator the app works fine. I've seen in previous answers, that someone knew, which framework is missing on the basis of the error. I would be glad if someone help me with it.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54767024/symbols-not-found-for-architecture-armv7-when-running-archive-in-xcode-and-py help?

Comment: Yes! I managed to install the app on my iPhone now, but on iPad i get a new error: ``` iPad doesn’t support any of pen.app’s architectures. You can add iPad armv7f architecture to pen.app’s Architectures build setting. ``` Any idea why?